# #include <WinUsb.h> produces compiler error in MFC app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, compiler-errors, winusb

I have a generic SDI application generated by VS2010 that I want to use to test the WinUsb API.  I have the current version of the WDK installed. According to postings I've read elesewhere, I should be able to set the VS2010 project include path to point to the WDK and add include WinUsb.h to do this.  So I added it to stdafx.h as follows

```
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#include <Winusb.h>
```

But when I compile I get errors

```
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\usb200.h(93): error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\usb200.h(93): error C2011: '<unnamed-tag>' : 'enum' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\htmlhelp.h(331) : see declaration of '<unnamed-tag>'
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\usb200.h(93): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\winddk\7600.16385.1\inc\api\usb200.h(93): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

The structure it is complaining about is

```
typedef union _USB_HIGH_SPEED_MAXPACKET {
    struct _MP {
        USHORT   MaxPacket:11;  /* 0..10 */
        USHORT   HSmux:2;        /* 11..12 */
        USHORT   Reserved:3;    /* 13..15 */
    };
    USHORT us;
  } USB_HIGH_SPEED_MAXPACKET, *PUSB_HIGH_SPEED_MAXPACKET;
```

and the IDE has underlined the _MP in red.

Answer (score 3):

The root of the problem comes in when the app is configured to use MBCS.
Inside of `mbctype.h`, which is included when selecting MBCS is a group of `#define` statements

```
/* bit masks for MBCS character types */

#define _MS     0x01    /* MBCS single-byte symbol */
#define _MP     0x02    /* MBCS punct */
#define _M1     0x04    /* MBCS 1st (lead) byte */
#define _M2     0x08    /* MBCS 2nd byte*/

#define _SBUP   0x10    /* SBCS upper char */
#define _SBLOW  0x20    /* SBCS lower char */
```

which occurs before the inclusion of `usb200.h`.
You can either not select MBCS (by using Unicode) or you can do as Lynn says and `#undef` it on the line above. But place the `#include` near the bottom of the list to avoid unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to add:

```
#undef _MP
```

just before the include of `Winusb.h`.

I believe it's an MFC-specific issue where MFC defines it as a pre-processor symbol, and the only workaround is to specifically undefine it so that the struct gets written out correctly. Supposedly, this has some other side-effects, so caveat emptor.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my mistake was not #including  before WinUsb.h

I made the erroneous assumption that the MFC headers would have ultimately included Windows.h but since this is a device related application apparently not.